# How can I validate reset password functionality using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The flow is as follow:

1. The user enters his email ID into `Forgot password` text field and click on OK
2. After that a reset password mail will get triggered
3. The user needs to go to a mail client and follows the reset password link to reset his password

Is it possible to validate this flow using Selenium?

Comment: IS THERE ANY REASON FOR WRITING THIS QUESTION WITH CAPS LOCK?

Comment: No Antonin . There isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done with just Selenium-WebDriver.

However you may be able to do something along the lines of:

1. Use Selenium-WebDriver to input the email address into the relevant field and click on 'OK'.
2. Use a library like Javamail to parse the subsequent email and retrieve the reset password link.
3. Navigate to the reset password link using Selenium-Webdriver.

I imagine this approach would probably be prone to all manner of trouble so I'd only really do this if it's absolutely essential to automate this process.

Comment: You're welcome, would you mind marking my answer as accepted if you're happy that your question has been answered?

Comment: How to ensure that this test case will pass every time? As the password will change everytime.